# GeoPandas Label Polygons

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geopandas

Given the shape file available [here](http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2015/shp/cb_2015_us_county_20m.zip): I'd like to label each polygon (county) in the map. Is this possible with GeoPandas?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

shpfile=<Path to unzipped .shp file referenced and linked above>
c=gpd.read_file(shpfile)
c=c.loc[c['GEOID'].isin(['26161','26093','26049','26091','26075','26125','26163','26099','26115','26065'])]
c.plot()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`c['geometry']` is a series comprised of `shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon` objects. You can verify this by checking

```
In [23]: type(c.ix[23, 'geometry'])
Out[23]: shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon
```

From the [Shapely docs](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) there is a method [`representative_point()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#general-attributes-and-methods) that

> Returns a cheaply computed point that is guaranteed to be within the
> geometric object.

Sounds ideal for a situation in which you need to label the polygon objects! You can then create a new column for your `geopandas` `dataframe`, `'coords'` like so

```
c['coords'] = c['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])
c['coords'] = [coords[0] for coords in c['coords']]
```

Now that you have a set of coordinates pertaining to each polygon object (each county), you can annotate your plot by iterating through your dataframe

```
c.plot()
for idx, row in c.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(s=row['NAME'], xy=row['coords'],
                 horizontalalignment='center')
```

[image]

Comment: @Fantastic! Thanks.

Comment: Instead of `annotate`, one can use `text`, which is handy when you want to contrast the data against the background: `ax.text(row.coords[0], row.coords[1], s=row[variable], horizontalalignment='center', bbox={'facecolor': 'white', 'alpha':0.8, 'pad': 2, 'edgecolor':'none'})`

Answer (score 84):

no need to loop, here is how you can annotate with apply:

```py
ax = df.plot()
df.apply(lambda x: ax.annotate(text=x['NAME'], xy=x.geometry.centroid.coords[0], ha='center'), axis=1);
```

Comment: Elegant and simple.

Comment: Did you make a typo: `xy=x.coords`?

Comment: The accepted answer worked for me, but not this one. I have two columns of interest for this example which are `name` and `geometry`. When apply is looping over them, and according to the prints it's not really getting the data row by row, it's more like column by column.

Comment: if anyone comes here and has the same labels as @h4k1m -> you need to set x.geometry.centroid.coords[0] as the xy in order for this solution to work

Comment: Thanks @Maik R. I think my code was originally as you suggested. But after some time I somehow thought that the `geometry` was unnecessary and edited the solution to make it more elegant. I apparently broke it instead. Thank you for correcting.

Comment: if anybody runs in this problem that  `x.name` yields index numbers do `x['name']`

Comment: perfect, easy and simple.

Comment: @tozCSS What if there are "empty" labels and you want to skip those? I am struggling to add the condition to the lambda expression

Comment: @StijnBerendse you can filter your df first like: `df[df['NAME'].notnull()].apply(...)`