# MatPlotLib Modify Custom Linear Segmented Colormap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

In relation to the accepted response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38882233/geopandas-matplotlib-plot-custom-colors/38885389#38885389):

What if I wanted to use 3 or more different, custom colors? Is it an easy edit to LinearSegmentedColormap?

This works for 2:

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

shpfile = 'cb_2015_us_county_20m.shp'
c = gpd.read_file(shpfile)
c = c.loc[c['GEOID'].isin(['26161','26093','26049','26091','26075',
                           '26125','26163','26099','26115','26065'])]

c['color'] = np.zeros(len(c))
# 23 is index for Washtenaw county and 1992 is index for Wayne county
c.ix[23, 'color'] = 1.0
c.ix[1992, 'color'] = 1.0

# create simple linear colormap that maps grey to blue
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mycmap', [(0, 'grey'), (1, 'blue')])

c.plot(column='color', cmap=cmap)
```

For 3, I tried:

```
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
    'mycmap', [(0, 'grey'), (0.5, 'red'), (1, 'blue')])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work in python 3? What went wrong? Don't forget that you have to update the values in `c['color']` if you want counties to start appearing as different colors.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have all values represented in my data frame (only had 0.5 and 1 with no zeros).

Comment: So if I had 0 set to grey, 0.5 to red, and 1 to blue and only had 0.5 and 1 values in my color column, it plots rows with 0.5 as grey instead of red, I'm assuming because that's the smallest number in the column. Is there a way to make this more absolute so 0.5 always plots as red no  matter what range of values are present in the color column?

Comment: I just used a series of if-elifs to outline different scenarios.

Comment: Ok, sorry I didn't get to your question in time. Using custom colormaps can get really annoying once you start trying to custom color more than a couple objects. If I had known you wanted a different color for each county from the get-go, I probably would have suggested using something other than `LinearSegmentedColormap`

Comment: No problem. The if-elif solution works perfectly fine for me. Thanks!

Comment: @Ianery: what would you recommend instead of LinearSegmentedColormap for more then 2 custom colors?

Comment: [`ListedColormap`](http://matplotlib.org/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap) off the top of my head. See also this example http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html

Comment: @Ianery what if I want a range of colors (spectrum as with a chloropleth) but if the value is 0.00000 or less, make it 'white'? I currently have a map that works except that the bottom 10% of values are treated as zeros and thus the corresponding counties are white. I can post a separate question if needed.

Comment: Check out `set_over` and `set_under`, and maybe `set_bad` as well. This method does exactly what I think you're looking for. There are examples out there (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548813/python-color-map-but-with-all-zero-values-mapped-to-black), but if you still have trouble you can either edit this question or post a new one. Good luck!

Comment: @Ianery, you're the best!